# How to make a random sample of chunk in an array/list (with replacement) instead of sampling the individual elements in the list list with python

Tags: python, arrays

I able to split a list into array of chunks from a list as demonstrated in the bellow python code:

```
def split_list(the_list, chunk_size):
    result_list = []
    while the_list:

result_list.append(the_list[:chunk_size])
            the_list = the_list[chunk_size:]

    return result_list

a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print split_list(a_list, 3)
```

which yield the bellow result of array of chunks:

```
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]
```

I am also aware of making a random sample through numpy.random.choice  (even with replacement) as demonstrated bellow:

```
import numpy as np
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
np.random.choice(a_list, size=20, 
replace=True)
```

which yields the bellow result:

```
#array([ 6,  9,  4,  9,  1,  1,  6, 10,  8,  5, 10,  6,  2,  6,  7,  1,  3,
    2,  7,  6])
```

**What I want**
I want to sample chunk in the array (while the elements of each chunk is left as it is) with replacement.

I am looking forward to get a code that will produce something like this:

```
# [[7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [10], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [10], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [10], [10], [7, 8, 9],, [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I picked the above sample of chunk myself, I need help to get a working python code to do that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the number of different chunks in your list (4 in your example), then randomly choose the index of the one you want (between 0 and 3 in your example).

So, you could do:

```
import math
import random

def random_chunk(lst, chunk_size):
    nb_chunks = int(math.ceil(len(lst)/chunk_size))
    choice = random.randrange(nb_chunks) # 0 <= choice < nb_chunks
    return lst[choice*chunk_size:(choice+1)*chunk_size]

a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
out = [random_chunk(a_list, chunk_size=3) for _ in range(20)]

print(out)

# [[10], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6],
#  [10], [7, 8, 9], [10], [10], [10], [7, 8, 9], [10], [10], [10], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [10]]
```